# ListLogPlot error when forcing y axes start at 0

Tags: plotting, version-10

I came across an error I can not circumvent.

When plotting the following:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[1/x, {x, 1, 100}]]
```

I receive a functioning plot. If I now want to add a specific PlotRange, i.e.

```
ListLogPlot[Table[1/x, {x, 1, 100}], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 2}}]
```

, I receive the following error:

```
First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[Automatic]. >>
```

Log[0] evaluates to negative infinity. I could fix this by starting the y axis at 0.01 or the likes - but I would still like to have a y-axis starting at zero.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think the nature of Log plots prevents the possibility of starting a log axis at `0`. Since your axis are powers of `10`, starting at `i` and ending at `f` let's say, your axis runs from `10^i` to `10^f`. In this way you only get `0` as the limiting behavior for `10^x` as `x->-Infinity`, so it's basically the linear plot equivalent of trying to start your axis at `-Infinity`.

Comment: It worked OK on v9, no errors. I'm adding v10 in tags

Comment: I would not say it *works* in 9.  It generates a plot but the illegal range seems to be ignored ( both the zero and the upper limit are ignored ).  @mondo if you really want a zero on your log scale you will have to work with the `Ticks` option.

Comment: indeed, v10 works better in the sense that it ignores the zero and respects your upper limit.  use `Quiet@ListPlot` to suppress the message.